# Suppress output from queries being executed using ADODB

Tags: php, mysql, adodb

I am working on some old code using `ADODB` in `PHP`.  Queries look like this:

```
$query = "SELECT `foo`                                                                                                                                                                
          FROM `bar`;                                                                                                                                           
$result = $conn->Execute( $query );
```

I am adding some AJAX functionality to the software but I realised that the `Execute` function is echoing/printing out the query - I don't want this:

```
(mysqlt): SELECT `foo`                                                                                                                                                                
           FROM `bar` &nbsp;
```

I believe `mysqlt` is the `MySQL` driver.

Is there a way to stop this output ?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try disabling debugging.

```
$query = "SELECT `foo` FROM `bar`";
$conn->Debug = false;
$conn->Execute($query);
```

Otherwise, try using output buffering:

```
ob_start();
$query = "SELECT `foo` FROM `bar`";
$conn->Execute($query);
ob_end_clean();
```